# Batch file to create multiple folders and copy files to all

Tags: batch-file, copy-paste

I need a batch file:
I have one folder which name is: 1 with multi files and sub folders

1. I will create 29 folders 2-30
2. Copy all files from folder name 1 to 2-30 folders

Folder names should be:

> 1-2-3-4...30

Thank you.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. Please edit your question to include any code you have already written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /l %%a in (2,1,30) do (
md "%%a"
xcopy "%CD%\1" "%CD%\%%a" /s
)
```

put this batch file in the directory where folder "1" is. but i do not think that naming folders with only one number is correct if you want to interact with it trough codes. try to name your folders like: folder1, folder2…

Comment: If folder 1 include sub folders 1/dir1 1/dir2 is not working.

Comment: @user699998, what is "not working"? read the help of [`xcopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) and find out how to copy also sub-directories and -files if that is what you need...

Comment: @HackR_360, you should use proper quotation to avoid trouble with paths containing spaces: `md "%%~a"` and `xcopy "%CD%\1" "%CD%\%%~a"`...

Comment: you guys are all true, see edit